# Override nested attributes name using I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, rails-i18n

I have two models `Store` and `StoreDetail` as the following:

```
class Store
   has_one :store_detail, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And StoreDetail:

```
class StoreDetail
   belongs_to :store, class_name: 'Store'
   belongs_to :state, class_name: 'State'
   belongs_to :city, class_name: 'City'
   belongs_to :zip_code, class_name: 'Zip Code'
end
```

And I override the attribute of state as the following:

```
attributes:
  store/store_detail:
    state: "State"
    city: "City"
    zip_code: "Zip Code"
```

But I got the validation messages:

```
Store detail state can't be blank
Store detail city can't be blank
Store detail zip code can't be blank
```

I want to make it without "Store detail", as the following:

```
State can't be blank
```

How can I override nested attributes ?

Comment: I'll look into it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validation messages:

```
class StoreDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :state_id, presence: true,
  message: I18n.t(:state_cant_be_blank)
end
```

And then in locales/*.yml

```
 en:
   state_cant_be_blank: State can't be blank
```

Comment: Yes, this is good. But OP wants to hack the _yaml_ file way it seems.. :)

Comment: I need to use I18n, If there solution for nested attributes.

Comment: I modified my answer to use I18t, check if that works for you please.

Answer (score 0):

This is  very possible with i18n:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        store_detail:
          attributes:
            state:
              blank: State can't be blank.
            city:
              blank: City can't be blank.
            zip_code:
              blank: Zip code cant't be blank.
```

**Very important**

- All of those nested labels starting with "en" and ending with "models" must be exactly as they are specified in the example.
- It is essential for the model name in the en.yml (or whichever kangage file you are using)
- Model name must match model.rb because this identifies the field names to be validated for activerecord
- The validation field names must match your schema.rb field names, like zip_code, not zip.
- The "blank:" identifier tells Rails activerecord component to do a string replace what you have in the i18n yaml file when that particular validation fails.

**Debugging i18n** (added)

- **Validate the YAML**: If you don't see the en.yml validation message you defined, but the default keeps showing, your en.yml is not functioning for some reason. YAML is very picky about spaces in the file and any trailing spaces in the file, etc. But it does not show any errors, it just reverts to using Rails default messages. Here's one YAML Lint tool: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/
- **Rails spec for i18n**: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html.
- **Debug i18n**: Use the gem i18n-tasks to create a comprehnsive report of the your i18n components : https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks
- **Application.rb**: Make sure you have i18n setup.

```
# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
  config.i18n.default_locale = :en
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

---

If you want custom error messages for activerecord type errors, you have to work through i18n. It isn't a tidy thing. It's not at all DRY, but it is what's available.

Comment: unfortunately The output is the same `Store detail state can't be blank`

Comment: Added a section on i18n debug to my answer. Good luck!